# R: Set Time Point as Zero and then Ascending and Descending Integers Around

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to make mark a specific time point as point zero and then the previous rows set as descending integers (-1, -2, etc) and the following rows as ascending integers (+1, +2, etc), but I'm completely stumped on how to do this. Here is a sample dataset:

```
Time = c("2023-07-28 22:14:00", "2023-07-28 22:15:00", "2023-07-28 22:16:00", "2023-07-28 22:17:00", "2023-07-28 22:18:00")
num = c(1000,1200,1234,980,1300)
df <- data.frame(Time = rep(Time, num), num = sequence(num))    
df[paste0('rand', seq_along(Time))] <- rnorm(length(Time) * sum(num))

head(df)
```

The goal would be to make 2023-07-28 22:16:00 = 0 and then descending integers before and ascending integers after time point. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no reference in your code to the object `ID`.

Comment: @ClaudioPaladini oops, sorry! Didn't look close enough while copy and pasting example data. Thanks for catching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
    mutate(Time = ymd_hms(Time), 
           dif = Time - ymd_hms('2023-07-28 22:16:00'),
           rank = dense_rank(dif) - row_number()[dif== 0])

                 Time  num       dif rank
1 2023-07-28 22:14:00 1000 -120 secs   -2
2 2023-07-28 22:15:00 1200  -60 secs   -1
3 2023-07-28 22:16:00 1234    0 secs    0
4 2023-07-28 22:17:00  980   60 secs    1
5 2023-07-28 22:18:00 1300  120 secs    2
```

You can then remove the `dif` column

Comment: is mutate apart of a package? I get ! could not find function "ymd_hms"

Comment: @ephackett include `library(tidyverse)` if you have older version, you will have to include `library(lubridate)` `ymd_hms` is in the `lubridate` library

Comment: I can get it to work, but it doesn't save the rank column as a new column in the df.

Comment: @ephackett that is because you have to save the new dataframe. ie `df1 <- df %>%....` You have to assign the results to something

Comment: Got it! It doesn't show up when I look at the table in RStudio, but I see it in colnames and can pull the data from it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: using the updated code in the question...

If your goal is to create a new column with numbers ascending or descending depending on a given "zero-point" you could try something like this.

```
Time = c("2023-07-28 22:14:00", "2023-07-28 22:15:00", "2023-07-28 22:16:00", "2023-07-28 22:17:00", "2023-07-28 22:18:00")
num = c(1000,1200,1234,980,1300)
df <- data.frame(Time = rep(Time, num), num = sequence(num))    
df[paste0('rand', seq_along(Time))] <- rnorm(length(Time) * sum(num))

head(df)

zero = "2023-07-28 22:16:00"
id_col = 'Time'

add_index = function(df,zero,id_col){
  
  df = df[order(df[,id_col]),]
  df$new_col = c(-rev(sequence(sum(df[,id_col] < zero))),rep(0,sum(df[,id_col] == zero)),sequence(sum(df[,id_col] > zero)))
  
  return(df)
}

df %>% 
  add_index(zero,id_col) %>% 
  head()
```

There are probably other ways of doing this,  but here is the output of this approach:

```
                 Time num      rand1       rand2       rand3       rand4      rand5 new_col
1 2023-07-28 22:14:00   1  0.2995052  1.64549561 -0.79780340 -1.07715548  0.4070298   -2200
2 2023-07-28 22:14:00   2 -1.6490923 -0.35256450  0.06296558  0.06870601 -0.3095747   -2199
3 2023-07-28 22:14:00   3 -0.5708513 -1.65916717  0.83986290 -2.09933862  0.3588580   -2198
4 2023-07-28 22:14:00   4 -0.3760261  0.89072105  0.56148014  0.08404197 -0.6248979   -2197
5 2023-07-28 22:14:00   5 -1.2998215  0.62532664  0.14171299 -0.25804508  0.5117224   -2196
6 2023-07-28 22:14:00   6 -0.4678034  0.03267064  0.76075794 -0.32648332 -3.3211990   -2195
```

Comment: Keep coming up with an error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, new_col, value = c(-105, -104, -103,  : 
  replacement has 106 rows, data has 105

Comment: Hmmm, same error even after I used your edited script. I'm sure I'm messing up something really simple.

Comment: the edited code should fix the issue.